# mongodb push to fixed array on php

Tags: php, mongodb

so apparently on the latest (unstable) version of mongo they implemented the following:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-991?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel

I am trying to get it to work on PHP but it doesn't work. I am using:

```
    $newData = array(
        '$push' => array(
            "$array" => $obj,
            '$size' => 10
        )
    );
    $collection->update(array("_id" => new MongoId("$IDIn")), $newData);
```

Now, it obviously is not working. I think the reason is either one of these two:

1. The PHP driver (1.3.2) does not yet support this functionality, although I doubt it since it is simply using a function that is defined on the server
2. The command is not $size: $integer - but if that is the case, I cannot find a description of it anywhere.

Anyone already had this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see examples of using this funcitonality here, from the JIRA: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/commit/b3687e73545f6d0d04f1992119308e7ab80d44e1

This one is of particular interest:

```
t.update( {_id:1}, { $push: { x: { $each: [ {a:3} ], $slice:-5, $sort: {a:1} } } } )
```

further down that page they have documented the code, i.e.:

```
// If we're in the "push all" case with slice, we have to decide how much of each
// of the existing and parameter arrays to copy to the final object.
```

You can find these sorts of nuggets at the bottom of the JIRAs where you see something similar to:

> auto added a comment - Jan 03 2013 05:26:11 PM UTC
>   Author:{u'date': u'2013-01-03T17:19:13Z', u'name': u'Alberto Lerner', u'email': u'alerner@10gen.com'}
>   Message: SERVER-991 SERVER-8008 Replaced $trimTo by $slice (but only accepting negative slices for now).
>   Branch: master
>   https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/commit/b3687e73545f6d0d04f1992119308e7ab80d44e1